# Why does `moduleName` in Webpack's stats include '+ 4 modules'?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-loader

Here's an example:

```
{
  "moduleId": 14,
  "moduleIdentifier": "/projects/sbt-vuefy/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!/projects/sbt-vuefy/src/test/scala/givers/vuefy/assets/vue/component-a.vue e03f6658ab7c5e6582e13283490782d2",
  "module": "./vue/component-a.vue + 4 modules",
  "moduleName": "./vue/component-a.vue + 4 modules",
  "type": "harmony import specifier",
  "userRequest": "./dependencies/component-b.vue",
  "loc": "7:29-39"
}
```

The above JSON comes from the below Webpack plugin code:

```
class Plugin {
  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.emit.tap("emit-hook", (compilation) => {
      for (let module of compilation.getStats().toJson().modules) {
        for (let reason of module.reasons) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(reason));
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Does anybody know what the `+ 4 modules` means? And, more importantly, is there a way to get rid of it?

The official doc (https://webpack.js.org/api/stats/#module-objects) doesn't say anything about it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug and can be turned off. See: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8507